# Why lock_guard not get destructed after another function is called?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

In my codebase I have two functions which looks something like this:

```
void inside() {
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(LOCK);
  cout << "Finished inside" << endl;
}

void outside() {
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(LOCK);
  inside();
  cout << "Finished outside" << endl;
}
```

This causes a deadlock in my codebase, which I find weird because I was under the impression that lock_guard gets destructed when it goes out of scope. I also tried with unique_lock, but got the same result. The only way I was able to resolve it was to call unlock prior to calling inside:

```
void outside() {
  LOCK.lock();
  // Do stuff
  LOCK.unlock();
  inside();
  cout << "Finished outside" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well, did it go out of scope?

Comment: In my mind it goes out of scope, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: It doesn't go out of scope until the function it's defined in finishes.  In a useful over-simplification, scope is defined by the closest curly braces {}'s the variable is defined in - in this case the {}'s of the function.  Until code execution completes that scope, it's in scope.

Comment: That explains it, thank you

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was under the impression that lock_guard gets destructed when it goes out of scope.

It does.  The problem is, you are creating 2 separate `lock_guard` objects in 2 separate scopes.  In `outside()`, you create one object that stays in scope while `inside()` is running.  `inside()` then creates its own object, which goes out of scope when `inside()` exits.  The object in `outside()` stays in scope until `outside()` exits.

That being said, note that `std::mutex` is not re-entrant.  Trying to lock a `mutex` when the lock is already owned by the calling thread is *undefined behavior*.  You have 2 `lock_guard` objects trying to own a lock to the same `mutex` from within the same thread.  That is why you are deadlocking.  You would need to use `std::recursive_mutex` instead to avoid that.  A thread can own multiple locks to a `recursive_mutex`, as long as it unlocks them all correctly.

Otherwise, if you really want `outside()` to unlock the `mutex` before entering `inside()`, the cleaner (and *safer*) way to handle that is to introduce a new scope in `outside()`, eg:

```cpp
void outside() {
  { // <--- starts a new scope here
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(LOCK);
  // Do stuff
  } // <-- ends the scope, destroying the lock_guard here
  inside();
  cout << "Finished outside" << endl;
}
```

Comment: So moral of the story is use recursive_mutex if the mutex is shared by multiple threads?

Comment: @doctopus • No, recursive_mutex if the mutex will be locked at different scopes / call chain within the same thread.

Comment: I see. Thank you